# Eclipse Build Error after DEXGuard install

Tags: android, eclipse, dexguard

I had put Dexguard's jar file on dropins folder.When I build my application on Eclipse IDE it shows an Error message.

> ```
> Error Occurred during the build.
> Error running builder 'Android optimizer and Obfuscator(DexGuard) on project 'HELLO'.
> com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.BaseBuilder.abortOnBadSetup(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/lJavaProject;Lcom/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/sdkProjectState;)V
> ```

I need to setup DEXGUARD. Help me to resolve my issue !

Note:
I had used android sdk revision 21.
Eclipse JUNO IDE

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that you combine the DexGuard plugin with the proper version of the Android plugin. The version numbers are documented in the manual. If you have a recent version of DexGuard, upgrading the Android plugin should solve the problem.